# Find first index of an item in an array in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

What is the simplest way to find the first index of some item in an array in Julia?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is `findfirst` and more generally `findnext`, which allows you to restart where you left off. One advantage of these two is that you don't need to allocate an output array, so the performance will be better (if you care).

Also, keep in mind that (unlike some other languages you may be used to) Julia's loops are fast, and as a consequence you can always write such simple functions yourself. To see what I mean, take a look at the implementation of `findnext` (in `base/array.jl`); there's nothing "fancy" about it, yet you get performance that is just as good as what you'd get if you had implemented it in C.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there must be a function for that :)

Comment: Can you add links to documentation for findfirst() and findnext()?

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/arrays/#Base.findfirst-Tuple{Any} and then just keep reading (`findnext` comes a little later in the same page).

Comment: fixed link for `findfirst`: [https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.findfirst-Tuple{Any}](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.findfirst-Tuple{Any})

Answer (score 8):

You can use ‍‍`findfirst` as follows:

```
A = [1, 4, 2, 3, 2]

function myCondition(y)
    return 2 == y
end

println( findfirst(myCondition, A) )

# output: 3
```

you can read more in this [Link](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.findfirst-Tuple%7BFunction,%20Any%7D)

Comment: According to the document, you can use ‍‍`isequal(2)` instead of `myCondition`, but I get the error: `no method matching isequal(::Int64)`.