# Julia version of R's Match?

Tags: r, julia

From R's help pages of `match()`:

Description:

> ‘match’ returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its
>   first argument in its second.

That is, I can give two vectors, `match(v1,v2)` returns a vector where the i-th element is the index where `v1[i]` appears in `v2`.

Is there such a similar function for Julia? I cannot find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102250/find-first-index-of-an-item-in-an-array-in-julia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`indexin`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/collections/?highlight=indexin#Base.indexin) (just as search fodder, this is also called `ismember` by Matlab).  It is very slightly different: it returns a vector where the i'th element is the *last* index where `v1[i]` appears in `v2`.

```
julia> v1 = [8,6,7,11]; v2 = -10:10;
       idxs = indexin(v1, v2)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 19
 17
 18
  0
```

It returns zero for the index of an element in `v1` that does not appear in `v2`.  So you can "reconstruct" the parts of `v1` that are in `v2` simply by indexing by the nonzero indices:

```
julia> v2[idxs[idxs .> 0]]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 8
 6
 7
```

If you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/092bcf46044a43060e0e251db5ad5a5f224547c4/base/array.jl#L853-L856), you'll see that it uses a dictionary to store and look up the indices.  This means that it only makes one pass over `v1` and `v2` each, as opposed to searching through `v2` for every element in `v1`.  It should be much more efficient in almost all cases.

If it's important to match R's behavior and return the first index, we can crib off the base implementation and just build the dictionary backwards so the lower indices overwrite the higher ones:

```
function firstindexin(a::AbstractArray, b::AbstractArray)
    bdict = Dict{eltype(b), Int}()
    for i=length(b):-1:1
        bdict[b[i]] = i
    end
    [get(bdict, i, 0) for i in a]
end

julia> firstindexin([1,2,3,4], [1,1,2,2,3,3])
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
 5
 0

julia> indexin([1,2,3,4], [1,1,2,2,3,3])
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4
 6
 0
```

Comment: `indexin` changed a bit with 0.7/1.0, now it returns `nothing` when no match is found

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this exists out of the box, but as @Khashaa's comment (and Tim Holy's answer to the other question) points out, you should be able to come up with your own definition fairly quickly. A first attempt:

```
function matched(v1::Array, v2::Array)
  matched = zeros(length(v1))
  for i = 1:length(v1)
    matched[i] = findfirst(v2, v1[i])
  end
  return matched
end
```

(note that I called the function `matched` because `match` is defined in Base for string matching, if you wanted to extend it you'd have to import `Base.match` first). You could certainly make this faster applying some of the tricks from the Julia docs' performance section if you care about performance.
This function should be doing what you're looking for if I understand correctly, try it with e.g.

```
v1 = [rand(1:10) for i = 1:100]
v2 = [rand(1:10) for i = 1:100]
matched2(v1,v2)
```