# Finding the dataframe row id in julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe where the number of rows is also contained in control records.

```
df = Dataframe(v1=["HMSTART", "a", "b", "c", "HMEND 5"])
```

I need to return the row number for the start and end control records.

i.e.
HMSTART is row 1
HMEND is row 5

is this possible without iterating through all the rows in the file and counting them ?

There are also other control records with counts which I need to look for and doing the calculation on the row numbers to find the number of records in each section would be more efficient than cycling thorough millions of records each time.

Comment: Are you just looking for the row numbers for rows that match "HMSTART" and "HMEND", or is it important that the `" 5"` in your example be extracted as well?

Comment: The 5 is important, the real file I'm using for testing has 845579 in that spot.

Comment: In your data, is the value `845579` just the row number where "HMEND" occurs? Is it the number of rows since the last "HMSTART"? Or is it an arbitrary number that has no meaning?

Comment: It is the record count, there are other sections with a record count in the same way, they are not at the start of the file.  I intend to make the calculation to check the number of records before pulling the dataframe apart for the other data.

Comment: I don't know if I'm understanding correctly. If there is only one row containing "HMSTART" and one row containing "HMEND", and they occur at the start and end of the column, respectively, the answer is trivial. But if there are more occurrences of these two sentinel values, or if they are not at the beginning and end of the column, then the answer depends on what those additional rows look like. Is there more to this DataFrame that you can give us as an example?

Comment: There should be only one HMSTART and one HMEND. There are two other pairs both are unique and are contained between the HMSTART and HMEND.  The start and end should not overlap and the record count should be correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234780/discussion-between-roy-jaques-and-paste).

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68096006) address what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a DataFrame in memory, searching it should be more efficient than copying out a huge row as an array.  Fortunately you can do that:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(v1=["HMSTART", "a", "b", "c", "HMEND 5"])
5×1 DataFrame
 Row │ v1
     │ String
─────┼─────────
   1 │ HMSTART
   2 │ a
   3 │ b
   4 │ c
   5 │ HMEND 5

julia> i = findfirst(x -> x == "HMSTART", df.v1)
1

julia> j = findfirst(x -> occursin("HMEND", x), df.v1)
5

julia> @show i, df.v1[i], j, df.v1[j]
(i, df.v1[i], j, df.v1[j]) = (1, "HMSTART", 5, "HMEND 5")
(1, "HMSTART", 5, "HMEND 5")
```

Whether you use 'j' as 5 or parse the 5 out of your HMEND tag likely depends on whether they are always the same (and if HMSTART is always 1 why look for it?)